# How to do a push with the current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am creating an application with tabs. These tabs are created by clicking on a menu item.
My problem is that repeated tabs are created. If you have already clicked on a menu item, I need you to do nothing (do not add it to my array).
`console.log (newArrayTabs)` works perfectly and does not add elements to my array, but I do not know how to use it in the `push`. If in the `push` I try to use `newArrayTabs` it does not work.

**I edit my code with @FunkeyFlo and i changed some code. This is the correct code for fix my issue**.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);

        ["openTabs",].forEach((method) => {
            this[method] = this[method].bind(this);
        });

        this.state = {
            navigation: {
                menu: [],
            },
            tabs:{
                tabsLi:[],    
            },

            textvalue : "",
            showtabs: true,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('json_menuFIN.php')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>{
                this.setState({navigation: data});
                //console.log(data)
            })
    }

    openTabs(e, url, iframe, trdtitle){
        e.preventDefault();
                const { tabs } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            showtabs: false,
        })
        if (this.state.tabs.tabsLi.includes(trdtitle) === false){
            this.setState({
                tabs: { tabsLi:[...new Set(this.state.tabs.tabsLi),trdtitle]},
            })
        }
    }
```

```
class Tabs extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="content-tabs" className="tabs">
            {( this.props.showtabs)  
                ? (
                    <>
                    <div className="waiting-leads">
                        <p>Parece que todavía no hay ningún lead...</p>
                        <h3>¡Ánimo, ya llega!</h3>
                        <img src={imgDinosaurio} alt="Dinosaurio"></img>
                    </div>
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <ul id="resizable" className="content" >
                        <List list={this.props.tabs.tabsLi} />
                    </ul>
            )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const List = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
        {props.list.map((value, index) =>         
            <li key={index}>
                <span>{value}</span>
                <Icon icon="cerrar" className='ico-cerrar' /*onClick={remove_tab(index)}*//>
            </li>
        )}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why do you push to state object already sent with setState ?

Comment: I have edited my code. I need to do a ``push`` to paint a ``<li>`` each time I click on a menu item (it's in a different component)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit confusing as tabs and tabsLi seem to be provided to the state as well as tabsLi being contained in tabs(?)

But to update an array in your state you could do the following instead

```
  openTabs(e, url, iframe, trdtitle) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { tabs } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      //...
      tabsLi: [...tabs.tabsLi, trdtitle], //instead of push
      //...
    })
  }
```

EDIT: it also works fine with components

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      listObj: { list: ['first value'] }
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    const newValue = 'new value';

    const { listObj } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      //...
      listObj: { list: [...listObj.list, newValue] }, //instead of push
      //...
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>
        <List list={this.state.listObj.list} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const List = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.list.map((i) => <div>{i}</div>)}</div>
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: The code does not work and it does not show any error. I have added the component so that it is understood where I need to use it.

Comment: I have updated my code and it still does not work. The part of the component with my old code does work, but the function does not paint anything.

Comment: In your code, part of my state was missing. Blame mine for not writing my original statements from the beginning. Currently it works, but as before, showing all the elements and we need to use a ``new Set`` so there are no repetitions. I have the same problem at the beginning ...